# JSON for jQuery EasyUI

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-easyui

I have been stuck with this for a while now.  I'm using EasyUI tree grid in my JSP with spring MVC.

In my controller, I generate a JSON string dynamically, the grid works great if I take the string and save it for a json file.

Looks like EasyUI takes in a url as json dataprovider.

In my controller, i have the following

```
jsonString = ''''the json string dynamically generated''''

modelAndView.addObject("jsonData", jsonString);
```

In the JSP file, how to i reference this jsonData for my EasyUI, I tried,
 `url: '${jsonData}'`, and many others and was not able to find anything on Google for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please work with:

var jsonData='${jsonData}';

jsonData=eval("("+jsonData+")");

$('#userDg').datagrid('loadData', jsonData);

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way.create an entity as below

```
public class DataGrid implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long total = 0L;
    private List rows = new ArrayList();

    public Long getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Long total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(List rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

}
```

and in your controller add this method.this must be your url for the datagrid.

```
    @RequestMapping("/findList")
        @ResponseBody
        public DataGrid dataGrid(User user, PageHelper ph) {
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            dg.setRows(yourList);
        dg.setTotal(total items in your table)
        return dg;//this will return json format as{"total":some number,"rows":[{},{},{}]}
        }
```